# Press button using selenium on yahoo finance doesn't work

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath, webdriverwait

I am trying to get the top stocks for the day so I go to https://finance.yahoo.com/gainers but I the want to edit the filters by pressing Edit.

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("https://finance.yahoo.com/gainers")
element = driver.find_element_by_class_name("Bgc($linkColor).Bgc($linkActiveColor):h.C(white).Fw(500).Px(20px).Py(9px).Bdrs(3px).Bd(0).Fz(s).D(ib).Whs(nw).Miw(110px)")
element.click()
```

This doesn't work. How can I fix it?

Comment: use data-reactid... xpath of "//span[@data-reactid='23']"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To click on the element <kbd>Edit</kbd> you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using `xpath`:

  ```
  driver.get("https://finance.yahoo.com/gainers")
  driver.find_element_by_xpath("//span[text()='Edit']").click()
  ```

---

Ideally, to click on the element you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59130200/selenium-wait-until-element-is-present-visible-and-interactable/59130336#59130336) for the `element_to_be_clickable()` and you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using `XPATH`:

  ```
  driver.get("https://finance.yahoo.com/gainers")
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//span[text()='Edit']"))).click()
  ```
- **Note**: You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```

Answer (score 0):

The java code below seems to work.

```
        WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
        driver.get("https://finance.yahoo.com/gainers");
        driver.manage().window().maximize();
        WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 30);
        WebElement editButton = wait
                .until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.cssSelector("button[data-reactid=\"23\"]")));
        editButton.click();
```

Cleaner locator

```
        WebElement editButton = wait
.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//button/span[contains(text(),'Edit')]")));
```